# Wordpress Querystring Repeat

Tags: wordpress

For a simple non-secure application, to keep the link text small, I am passing a querystring with each record ID from an 'edit' column with a many rows in a Wordpress page.

```
<td><a href='$thispage?z=$id'>edit</a></td>
```

Each time I click a link, the browser address bar shows a repeating querystring.
"?z=1?z=1?z=1?z=1....
I know the link is relative, and using  full url didn't fix it (not on WAMP anyway). Anybody have any ideas that will avoid posting, javascript etc ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you echo $thispage each time you click to this?

Comment: I think $thispage is problem here.

Comment: Many thanks Quỳnh - perfect. I had changed the def for $thispage from PHP_SELF  to  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: Can I add this to answer and you vote up for me?

Answer (score 0):

`$thispage` is problems here.

So you can change it to something like `site_url().'/directory?z=$id'`